# Scoping a variable shared by multiple async callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, asynchronous

I'm using the [async.js library by Caolan McMahon](http://caolanmcmahon.com/async.html) and the [jQueryUI progress bar](http://jqueryui.com/demos/progressbar/) to provide feedback to the user while several async calls gather data and fill in elements of a complex graph.

My question is:  **What's the best way to scope data that needs to be shared by the asynchronous methods?**

This is a *simplified* example of what I'm doing.  I've got it working using global variables but they disturb me a little and make jsLint complain.  Passing arguments or scoping at the Document Ready function breaks it.

The counterparts to `updateA()` et. al. in my real code are hundreds of lines and include XHR calls.

### JavaScript:

```
// global variables.  Bad?
var steps = 3;
var ticked = 0;
var otherCounter = 0;

$(function() {
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value: 0
    });

    async.parallel([
        function(onDoneCallback) {
        updateA(onDoneCallback);},
        function(onDoneCallback) {
        updateB(onDoneCallback);},
        function(onDoneCallback) {
        updateC(onDoneCallback);}
    ], function(err, results) { // final callback when they're all done
        tickProgress('All done after ' + ticked + ' ticks.', true);
    });
});

function tickProgress(message) {
    var curvalue = $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value');
    var done = false;

    if (arguments.length > 1) {
        done = arguments[1];
    }

    $('#progress_text').html(message);

    if (done) {
        $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', 100);
    }
    else {
        $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', curvalue + 100 / steps);
    }

    ticked++; // global OK here?
}

function updateA(onDoneCallback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#a').html('A is foo. otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
        tickProgress('updated A at otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
        otherCounter++;
        onDoneCallback(null, 'A done');
    }, 1000);

}

function updateB(onDoneCallback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#b').html('B is bottle. otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
        tickProgress('updated B at otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
        otherCounter++;
        onDoneCallback(null, 'B is OK');
    }, 100);
}

function updateC(onDoneCallback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#c').html('C is cauliflower. otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
        tickProgress('updated C at otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
        otherCounter++;
        onDoneCallback(null, 'C done');
    }, 2000);
}
```

### HTML:

```
<p id="progress_text" style="background:yellow">Loading...</p>
<div id="progressbar"></div>
<hr />
<h2>a</h2>
<p id="a">Looking up a...</p>

<h2>b</h2>
<p id="b">Looking up b...</p>

<h2>c</h2>
<p id="c">Looking up c...</p>
```

### Fiddle:

I've got [the sample code at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jSqrC/8/) if you want to bang on it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[david](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423491/david) turned me on to this approach [the other day](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/318274#318274) in the JS chat room.  [See it work at jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/jSqrC/11/)

It makes use of a global object, but I like the logical encapsulation of the methods within the object better than the suggestions by [jAndy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928273/scoping-a-variable-shared-by-multiple-async-callbacks/4928329#4928329) and [kirilloid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928273/scoping-a-variable-shared-by-multiple-async-callbacks/4928327#4928327).

```
var Updater = (function() {
    var steps = 3;
    var ticked = 0;
    var otherCounter = 0;

    function a(onDoneCallback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#a').html('A is foo. otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
            tickProgress('updated A at otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
            otherCounter++;
            onDoneCallback(null, 'A done');
        }, 1000);

    }

    function b(onDoneCallback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#b').html('B is bottle. otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
            tickProgress('updated B at otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
            otherCounter++;
            onDoneCallback(null, 'B is OK');
        }, 100);
    }

    function c(onDoneCallback) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#c').html('C is cauliflower. otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
            tickProgress('updated C at otherCounter ' + otherCounter);
            otherCounter++;
            onDoneCallback(null, 'C done');
        }, 2000);
    }

    function tickProgress(message) {
        var curvalue = $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value');
        var done = false;

        if (arguments.length > 1) {
            done = arguments[1];
        }

        $('#progress_text').html(message);

        if (done) {
            $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', 100);
        }
        else {
            $('#progressbar').progressbar('option', 'value', curvalue + 100 / Updater.getSteps());
        }
        Updater.tick(); // global OK here?
    }

    return {
        a: a,
        b: b,
        c: c,
        tickProgress: tickProgress,
        tick: function() {
            ticked++;
        },
        getTicks: function() {
            return ticked;
        },
        getSteps: function() {
            return steps;
        }
    };
}());

$(function() {
    $('#progressbar').progressbar({
        value: 0
    });

    async.parallel([
        function(onDoneCallback) {
        Updater.a(onDoneCallback);},
        function(onDoneCallback) {
        Updater.b(onDoneCallback);},
        function(onDoneCallback) {
        Updater.c(onDoneCallback);}
    ], function(err, results) { // final callback when they're all done
        Updater.tickProgress('All done after ' + Updater.getTicks() + ' ticks.', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

In generall, it's always a great idea to create your own <strike>closured</strike> `Function-Context'ed` "region". You can do that by wrapping a self invoking anonymous function around your application. This could look like

```
(function(window, document, $) {
     // all your app logic goes into here
     var steps = 3;
     var ticked = 0;
     var otherCounter = 0;

     // ...
}(this, this.document, jQuery))
```

That way, you never clobber the global namespace. Of course you need to have a global object sometimes, but you really should try to avoid that unless absolutly necessary.

Answer (score 3):

You could put the global vars into a "state" object and pass it to all the callback functions. e.g.

```
$(function() {
    var progressState = {
        steps: 3,
        ticked: 0,
        otherCounter: 0
    };

    $('#progressbar').progressbar({value: 0});

    async.parallel(
      [
        function(onDoneCallback) {updateA(onDoneCallback, progressState);},
        function(onDoneCallback) {updateB(onDoneCallback, progressState);},
        function(onDoneCallback) {updateC(onDoneCallback, progressState);}
      ],
      function(err, results) { // final callback when they're all done
        tickProgress('All done after ' + progressState.ticked + ' ticks.', true, progressState);
      }
    );
});
```

You would then change updateA, updateB, updateC and tickProgress to use the provided state object, instead of the global vars.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @kirilloid, but I don't like the excessive argument passing this approach requires as much as having a global object.